# Extra space when separating dates using separate() and str_c() functions

Tags: r, string

I am getting incredibly frutstrated because I do not see where this extra space is coming from and I am about at my wits end.

I would like to split a 'Date' variable to Start and End dates.
An example of the original 'Date' entry: January 1 - March 1, 2015
And I would like to separate this into a Start date: January 1, 2015
And an End date: March 1, 2015

My code:

```
df %>%
  separate(Date, into = c("Start", "End"), sep = "-") %>%
  separate(End, into = c("End", "Year"), sep = ", ") %>%
  mutate(End = str_c(End, Year, sep = ", "),
         Start = str_c(Start, Year, sep = ", ")) %>%
  select(-Year)
```

The end date output is as expected, but my beginning date is "January 1 , 2015" and I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra space. When I include the spaces as a separator it gives me all NA entries. So, if I were to say for the first line `sep = " - "` then I end up getting NAs for my Start date variables. I've also tried `extra = "merge"` and I've tried separating out the Start month and day but I cannot get rid of this extra space.

Thank you in advance for your help - I really appreciate it.

Comment: maybe: `sep = " -"`

Comment: I've tried that too - gives me NA values.

Comment: could you post `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Done - is that what you were looking for? I'm still an amateur at R. Let me know if I need to fix it. Thanks so much.

Comment: You did not copy/paste the whole output of `dput(head(df))` `structure...` You can omit the columns that are not needed to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! The trick here is to remove the trailing white space on the right side of the string by using `str_trim()`. Here is the corrected code.

```
date %>%
  separate(dates, into = c("Start", "End"), sep = "-") %>%
  separate(End, into = c("End", "Year"), sep = ", ") %>%
  mutate(End = str_c(End, Year, sep = ", "),
         Start = str_c(str_trim(Start), Year, sep = ", ")) %>%
  select(-Year)
```

**Output**

```
            Start             End
1 January 1, 2015   March 1, 2015
2   March 2, 2015  August 5, 2015
```